# Are groups of component type always of Lie type, alternating or sporadic?

Tags: finite-groups

In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups it was written that

"A group is said to be of component type if for some centralizer C of an involution, C/O(C) has a component (where O(C) is the core of C, the maximal normal subgroup of odd order). These are more or less the groups of Lie type of odd characteristic of large rank and alternating groups, together with some sporadic groups."

Can the words "more or less" be left out in this sentence or what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finite simple groups of component type include *most* of the Chevalley groups (of Lie type) of odd characteristic, most of the alternating groups,and many of the sporadic simple groups.
It does not mean *all* groups of Lie type of odd characteristics.